# zero flag in verilog problems

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I am attempting to build a 32 bit ALU in verilog and I've only done a small bit of behavioral verilog before, so I'm having some difficulty with this code:

```
module ZERO_FLAG(flag, control, inputA, inputB);
  input [2:0] control;
  input [31:0] inputA, inputB;
  output flag;

  reg flag;

  always @(control or inputA or inputB) begin
    case (control)
      1: flag <= (|(inputA ~& inputB));
      3'bxxx, 3'bxx0, 3'bxx1, 3'bx0x,
      3'bx00, 3'bx01, 3'bx1x, 3'bx10,
      3'bx11, 3'b0xx, 3'b0x0, 3'b0x1,
      3'b00x, 3'b000, 3'b01x, 3'b010,
      3'b011, 3'b1xx, 3'b1x0, 3'b1x1,
      3'b10x, 3'b100, 3'b101, 3'b11x,
      3'b110, 3'b111: flag <= 0;
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

For some reason Modelsim is simply unhappy with the NAND between inputA and inputB in the case of 1. The basic idea is that I only want to throw a zero flag when subtraction is happening, and then I want the result to be an OR reduced bitwise NAND of the two inputs. Thoughts?

Comment: NB `default: flag <= 0;` might be easier than, `3'bxxx, 3'bxx0, 3'bxx1, 3'bx0x, ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try rewriting the line as:

```
1: flag <= |(~(inputA & inputB));
```

Comment: A sweet, that works, but also apparently I just should have been using &~ instead. Also it worked once I switched to ~^, like I should have been for the zero flag, but this also works!

Answer (score 2):

It is worth mentioning to complement the other answers that under IEEE 1364.1-2002 A.8.6 That `~&` is valid Verilog syntax but available only as a unary operator. This means that it will only take a right hand argument.

```
 &(4'b0000) => 1'b0
 &(4'b0101) => 1'b0
 &(4'b1111) => 1'b1

~&(4'b0000) => 1'b1
~&(4'b0101) => 1'b1
~&(4'b1111) => 1'b0
```

The available unary operators are:

```
+, -, !, ~, &, ~&, |, ~|, ^, ~^, ^~
```

Of these `&, ~&, |, ~|, ^, ~^, ^~` are reduction operators, as shown above will reduce down to 1 bit values. The `^` implies XOR.

The available bitwise operators :

```
+, -, *, /, %, ==, !=, ===, !==, &&, ||, **,
<, <=, >, >=, &, |, ^, ^~, ~^, >>, <<, >>>, <<<
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no binary NAND in Verilog. The only binary bitwise operators are AND(&), OR(|), XOR(^) and XNOR(both ~^ and ^~).